# How can I make find() work with a set of structs?

Tags: c++, struct, set, find, containers

I am using a `set` to hold structs which contain several strings. I want to be able to use the `find()` functionality of sets. However, since the set is holding structs, it doesn't work. I want `find()` to look only at one of the strings in the struct. How can this be done?

Here's the code that I tried to use. It works fine except for the part where `find()` is used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
    string key;
    string data;
};

bool operator<(const test & l, const test & r)
{
    return l.key < r.key;
}

bool operator==(const test & l, const test & r)
{
    return l.key == r.key;
}

set<test> s;

int main()
{
    test newmember;
    newmember.key = "key";
    newmember.data = "data";
    s.insert(newmember);
    s.find("key");
}
```

Here are the error messages that I get when I try to compile it:

```
test.cpp:30:7: error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
    s.find("key");
    ~~^~~~
In file included from test.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/set:65:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_set.h:429:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [4]' to 'const key_type' (aka 'const test') for 1st argument
      find(const key_type& __x)
      ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_set.h:433:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [4]' to 'const key_type' (aka 'const test') for 1st argument
      find(const key_type& __x) const
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you `operator<` and `operator==` to your struct instead of overloading the global operator, I find it much cleaner; example:

```
struct test
{
  string key;
  string data;

  bool operator<(const test& rhs) const
  {
    return key < rhs.key;
  }

  bool operator==(const test& rhs) const
  {
    return key == rhs.key;
  }
};
```

Now on to your real problem - your are passing a string to the `find()` function, but it only accepts structs of type `test`. In order to do so, add a constructor for automatic conversion, so the final struct would look like this:

```
struct test
{      
  string key;
  string data;

  test(const std::string& strKey = "", const std::string& strData = "")
  : key(strKey),
    data(strData) {}

  bool operator<(const test& rhs) const
  {
    return key < rhs.key;
  }

  bool operator==(const test& rhs) const
  {
    return key == rhs.key;
  }
};
```

Then passing a string to `find()` would automatically call the constructor and create a temporary `test` struct containing only the relevant key. Note that in this special case, the constructor must not be declared `explicit`.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to put your structs into `set` you have to specify `operator<` for your struct. You can make the `operator<` return result from comparing corresponding string members.

To be able to use `find` you can specify `operator==` for your struct to return `true` if corresponding string members are equal.

Sample:

```
    // code from your question used here

    int main()

{
    test newmember;
    newmember.key = "key";
    newmember.data = "data";

    test findMember;
    findMember.key = "key";
    // as operator== and operator< doesn't care about data field we can left it be
    // initialized by default constructor

    s.insert(newmember);
    s.find(findMember);
}
```

If you want to call `find()` with `string` parameter you can provide an implicit constructor from `string` for your `test` struct for example like this:

```
struct test {
//...
  test(const string &in_key) : key(in_key) {}
//...
};
```

But usage of implicit constructors isn't a good technique, because it can lead to some unpredictable conversions somewhere further in your code.

Comment: What's the code to do that? I can overload the < operator but the same method doesn't work for ==.

Comment: @z-buffer: see update version of my answer. Your problem is, that you have to provide `find()` with instance of your `test` struct.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, in order to make [`std::set::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) work with your `struct`, you don't need to specify `operator==`, as explained for [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

> [...] two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

However, your actual problem is, that you can't search for parts of your `struct` by using `find()` prior to [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14). Prior to C++14, `find()` expects an element as argument, whose type matches the type of elements stored in the set. For your case, this means that you have to provide an instance of `test`. However, as your `operator<` compares only the `key` variables, you can use a dummy value for the `data` variable, for example, as follows:

```
test newmember;
newmember.key = "key";
newmember.data = "data";
s.insert(newmember);

auto it = s.find(test{ "key", "" });  // "" is the dummy variable.
std::cout << it->key << ", " << it->data << std::endl;
```

Output:

> key, data

Please be aware that your `operator<` which compares only the `key` variables has a side effect: Two instances of `test` can only be stored in the set if their `key` variables are different, even if their `data` variables are different. For example, if you append the following code to the code above, then `newmember` will not be inserted (again):

```
newmember.data = "otherdata";
s.insert(newmember);  // Insertion fails!
for (auto const& t : s) {
    std::cout << t.key << ", " << t.data << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> key, data

Consequently, if you want to store multiple elements with the same key, then you might have to choose a different container.

Anyway, if a set of `struct` is fine for you and you can make use of [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), then you can also use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)
instead of defining `operator<` for your `struct`:

```
auto comp = [](const test& t1, const test& t2) { return t1.key < t2.key; };
std::set<test, decltype(comp)> s(comp);
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/r29qyA)

---

### C++14

Since [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14), you can use `find()` to do a "transparent comparison" as explained on [`std::set::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find).
This means, that you can find an element that compares *equivalent* to the given argument.
In detail this means, that you have to define `operator<` and your set as follows:

```
bool operator<(const test& t, const std::string& str) { return t.key < str; }
bool operator<(const std::string& str, const test& t) { return str < t.key; }
bool operator<(const test& t1, const test& t2) { return t1.key < t2.key; }
std::set<test, std::less<>> s;
```

Then you can perform your `find()` operation as you would have expected it to work:

```
test newmember;
newmember.key = "key";
newmember.data = "data";
s.insert(newmember);

auto it = s.find("key");
std::cout << it->key << ", " << it->data << std::endl;
```

Output:

> key, data

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/WtQyOh)

Answer (score 1):

Only you have to override operator<() function to enhance find function.
In your case simply replace operator<() function as..

```
bool operator<(const offer& t1) const {
    if(this->key< t1.key)
        return true;
    else if(this->key == t1.key){
         if(this->data < t1.data)
             return true;
         else
             return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```